# Query DHT for the total number of active peers

Tags: bittorrent, dht, kademlia

Assume there is a P2P file sharing system which has no trackers but only a DHT.

How to know the number of all active peers uploading/downloading a specific file?

Is it just keep querying the DHT by `get_peers` to get new peers? Are there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

The *distributed* part in the DHT makes it hard to get the exact number of peers in a swarm from it. Technically it's also unneeded and not a very useful number, as its only necessary to get in contact with only one other peer in the swarm and then the ***P***eer**EX**change extension will give plenty more peers in a more efficient way than the DHT.

Some clients also support the *BEP33 DHT scrape* extension that can give a approximate number of peers registered in the DHT with a max capacity of ca 6000.
Unfortunately it's badly designed and has a vulnerability making it the currently most potent vector for UDP amplification attacks using the BitTorrent protocol. It has a BAF (Bandwidth Amplification Factor) of 13.4 The attack is called *Distributed Reflective Denial of Service (DRDoS)* and is decribed in this [paper.](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/woot15/woot15-paper-adamsky.pdf) If this vector starts to get used it may be necessary to speedly remove this extension from the protocol.

Comment: The number of peers is a very good indicator of the popularity of the file being shared. This is why I want to know how to measure it in DHT.

Comment: Yes, but statistics are *nice to haves* and not necessary for the protocol to work. It's also very easy to fake stats in a distributed system like the DHT by doing a eclipse attack on the info_hash. This could be mitigated somewhat if BEP42 was enforced, unfortunately it's not.

Comment: I agree that in hindsight I could have done much better with BEP33. But if issues become troubling we can always improve it instead of removing it. It *is* a commonly requested feature after all.

Comment: So are there any alternative ways to quantify the popularity of contents if the number of peers is hard to acquire?

Comment: He said it would be hard to get an *exact number*. Do you actually need exact numbers for a popularity assessment?

Comment: @the8472 Not necessarily, as long as I can know the relative size of different swarms